# How can I get rid of the format specifier in Rails 4.1 routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have a controller called `UsersController`, and I have `resources :users` in my routes.rb file. `rake routes` shows such routes as `users/:id(.:format)`, but I want my routes to be of the form `users/:id` instead (i.e. asking for users/7.html will return an error.) How can I do that?

Comment: (:format) is an optional part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually quite simple:

```
resources :users, :format => false
```